# java.lang.SecurityException:Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy when registering receiver android.content.IIntentReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-securityexception

This error occurs when users have the first login after installing my app. But in the next launch (when the user already logged in) the app works fine.

In my app I am using a `BroadcastReceiver` which is used for checking internet connectivity.

So to be specific, the app is having above mentioned `Exception` while registering that `BroadcastReceiver`. Any help would be highly appereciated!

My logcat is like below

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.myproject/com.android.myproject.MapActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@43155660 (pid=24211) when registering receiver android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy@43151368
1 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2762)
2 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2791)
3 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1288)
4 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
5 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
6 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
7 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
8 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
9 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:845)
10 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
11 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@43155660 (pid=24211) when registering receiver android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy@43151368
13 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
14 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
15 at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.registerReceiver(ActivityManagerNative.java:2228)
16 at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1356)
17 at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1324)
18 at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1318)
19 at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:423)
20 at com.android.myproject.MapActivity.onResumeOperations(MapActivity.java:584)
21 at com.android.myproject.MapActivity.onResume(MapActivity.java:618)
22 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
23 at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5203)
24 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2752)
```

In order to clarify my question, my `onResumeOperations()` look like

```
 public void onResumeOperations(){
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )&& !isFinishing()) {
        ShowGpsDialog();
    } else {
        removeGpsDialog();
    }

    registerReceiver(internetConnectionReciever, new IntentFilter(
            "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
    registerReceiver(GpsChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
    isRecieverRegistered = true;

    if (AndyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)
            && manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        if (!isDataRecieved) {

            checkStatus();
            startLocationUpdateService();
           // getPreReservations();
        }
    }

    registerIsApproved();

    startRepeatingChecker();
}
```

this `onResumeOperations()` is called in `onResume()`. And as I previously mentioned, the problem occurs when registering `internetConnectionReceiver`.

Comment: can u share the  logcat?

Comment: please check my edited question

Comment: Can you please post your `MapActivity.java:618` along with some other relevant code?

Comment: specifically in this line `registerReceiver(internetConnectionReciever, new IntentFilter( "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));`  the problem occurs ; where `internetConnectionReciever` is a `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Please share more code and update your question.

Comment: please check my edited ques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means there was an error communicating with another process handling an `Intent`.

this error can happen sending an `intent` with `intent extras` being too big, bigger than max transaction size (1Mb).

Passing High resolution photos or big file via `extras` is not recommended, the best practice is to save the file on the external storage get a `Uri` reference to it and send this ref as `String` in your intent's extra

```
yourIntent.putExtra("key", yourUri.toString)
```

Also try `android:exported="true"` in `activity` tag

```
<activity
android:name=".your_activity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:exported="true">
```

setting the exported tag to `true` means that another application not related to my app can access it